# Почему у меня иногда добавление репутации не высвечивается?

Tags: поддержка, репутация

Сначала все шло нормально, все высвечивалось. В последние дни начал замечать, что даже если ставят плюс, то репутация увеличивается, но приятный зеленый цвет иногда не появляется. Такое не всегда, а иногда. Разве так и должно быть?

Comment: @VladSpirin По моемуТС имеет ввиду зелень на иконке "рюмочка" вверху справа в топбар.

Comment: @0xdb ТС должен пояснить тогда, а то вообще непонятки. Как-то в догадки сложно играть, да и времени на это жалко

Comment: @VladSpirin Ну да, формулировки ТЦ оставлят желать лучшего, но в данном случае - "если ставят плюс" и "принятый ответ" всё таки разные вещи.

Comment: @Suvitruf, какой дубликат, там вообще мимо же.

Comment: @VladSpirin, вроде всё вполне ясно. Тут о репутации в углу, а там о списке собственных ответов в вопросах с принятым ответом.

Comment: @Qwertiy проморгал. Сорри.

Comment: Чет лажаю в последнее время, надо отойти от дел на 3-4 дня. Как раз видяху новую потестить. Стократно извиняюсь

Comment: @VladSpirin Все ок, бывает, не надо извинятся, все мы местами ошибаемся :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зелёный лейбл появляется только если суммарное изменение репутации по всем сайтам сети положительное. Если где-то ты получил минусы, которые ещё не просматривал в верхнем меню, а плюсов недостаточно, чтобы их перевесить, то лейб не отображается.

Однако, если его всё равно кликнуть, то можно увидеть детальную информацию, где и что поменялось.